# Qt/QML: Accessing a ListView after a Loader has loaded it to jump to a specific item/page

Tags: qt, components, qml, loader

I have a QML application that is basically just a ListView which displays a number of "chapters", which in turn each include one or more "pages".

Since I don't know how many chapters and pages a QML might have in production, I'm using a `Loader` to load the pages on demand, which should save some memory.

So the problem is that I want to "jump" to a certain story and page at the push of a button. I added a few buttons to the example which jump to different chapters already.

You can vertically flick between chapters and horizontally between pages of each chapter.

The problem I have is that I can't figure out how to get the `ListView` containing the pages to jump to a specific page after switching/loading a specific chapter. Basically I'm missing something like `pagesView.currentPage = 5` or something similar.

What would be a good way to get this working?

[image: Screenshot]

The corresponding QML. You can run this with qmlscene.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2


ApplicationWindow {
    width: 1024
    height: 768


    Component {
        id: pageViewComponent
        ListView {
            id: pagesView
            property int storyIndex: chapterView.modelData
            orientation: ListView.Horizontal; clip: true
            model: 20; snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: pagesView.width; height: pagesView.height
                color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1)
                border.color: "black"
                Text { text: "Page " + modelData; anchors.centerIn: parent; color: "white" }
            }

        }
    }


    Rectangle {
        color: "black"
        anchors.fill: parent

        // Chapters 
        ListView {
            id: chapterView
            model: 8
            anchors.fill: parent
            snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem

            delegate: Rectangle {
                color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1)
                width: chapterView.width; height: chapterView.height

                Rectangle {
                    width: parent.width * 0.6; height: parent.height * 0.6
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    Loader { 
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        sourceComponent: pageViewComponent 
                    }
                }


                Text {
                    x: 50; y: 50
                    color: "white"; font.pointSize: 30
                    text: "Chapter " + modelData
                }

                Flow {
                    Button {
                        text: "Go to Chapter 2, Page 7"
                        onClicked: { 
                            chapterView.positionViewAtIndex(2, ListView.Beginning)
                            //
                            //
                            // After jumping to the correct chapter, we obviously have to jump
                            // to the correct page after the Loader for that specific chapter has
                            // completed loading the pages of the chapter.
                            //
                            //
                        }
                    }

                    Button {
                        text: "Go to Chapter 1, Page 1"
                        onClicked: {
                            chapterView.positionViewAtIndex(1, ListView.Beginning)
                            // dito
                        }
                    }

                    Button {
                        text: "Go to Chapter 5, Page 2"
                        onClicked: { 
                            chapterView.positionViewAtIndex(5, ListView.Beginning)
                            // dito
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [Loader.item](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#item-prop) to access the dynamically created `pagesView`. So you can `idOfTheLoader.item.positionViewAtIndex(7, ListView.Beginning)` to change pages.

Comment: @mcchu - that would access the loader of the current item, not the one you are going to. Plus the call to it must be scheduled to run when it has loaded its content, with a lambda and parameter capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my way of doing this:

1. Define properties in `pagesView` that will allow it to update it's appearance and state:

   ```
   Component {
       id: pageViewComponent
       ListView {
           id: pagesView

           // Begin inserted code
           property int chapterIndex: -1
           property ListView chapterView: null
           Connections {
               target: chapterView
               onSelectedPageChanged: {
                   if (chapterIndex === chapterView.selectedChapter)
                       pagesView.positionViewAtIndex(chapterView.selectedPage, ListView.Beginning)
               }
           }
           onChapterIndexChanged: {
               if (chapterView && chapterIndex === chapterView.selectedChapter)
                   pagesView.positionViewAtIndex(chapterView.selectedPage, ListView.Beginning)
           }
           // End inserted code

           orientation: ListView.Horizontal; clip: true
           model: 20; snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
           delegate: Rectangle {
               width: pagesView.width; height: pagesView.height
               color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1)
               border.color: "black"
               Text { text: "Page " + modelData; anchors.centerIn: parent; color: "white" }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Define the properties that will store the whole thing's state (that is, current chapter & page):

   ```
   property int selectedChapter: 0
   property int selectedPage: 0
   ```
3. Update top-level ListView position according to `selectedChapter` property:

   ```
   onSelectedChapterChanged: positionViewAtIndex(selectedChapter, ListView.Beginning)
   ```
4. Setup `pagesView`'s properties when it's created:

   ```
   Loader {
       id: pagesViewLoader
       anchors.fill: parent
       sourceComponent: pageViewComponent
       onLoaded: {
           item.chapterIndex = Qt.binding(function() { return modelData })
           item.chapterView = chapterView
       }
   }
   ```
5. Trigger chapter and page change from `Button`:

   ```
   // Define method in top-level ListView
   ListView {
       id: chapterView
       function goTo(chapter, page) {
           selectedChapter = chapter
           selectedPage = page
       }
   // ...

   // Call method from onClicked handler
   Button {
       text: "Go to Chapter 2, Page 7"
       onClicked: {
           chapterView.goTo(/* chapter */ 2, /* page */ 7)
       }
   }
   ```

### Important Notes

#### Note 1

In the 4th step `modelData` is not set directly, instead it is wrapped into `Qt.binding` function call. This is how you bind to value from JavaScript. This is necessary because ListView reuses it's delegate instances, and `pagesView` instance can be reused with different `modelData` values after single `onLoaded` message.

#### Note 2

At first I used two property assignments in `onClicked` without wrapping them in `goTo` function:

```
chapterView.selectedChapter = chapter
chapterView.selectedPage = page
```

but this led to error in the second line (`chapterView is not defined`). When first line executes, `chapterView` scrolls to the selected chapter, and current delegate item is removed from the scene since it is no longer needed. I can't tell how this "removed from the scene" is done technically, but the result is that after the first line `chapterView` is no longer defined. Hence the need to wrap these two assignments in a single function call.

Comment: Nice answer. I'll give it a try and get back to you! QML sometimes can be a bit hard to wrap your head around if you are used to develop applications using traditional tools. ;)

Comment: Update: Works from what I can see. I learned a few things from your answer that will help me in the future: 1) Qt.binding() -- how did I miss this?; 2) Custom `function`s in QML objects. Thank you!

Comment: For completeness I have made this gist with a working example: https://gist.github.com/bastibense/7f949e2f791b4db27c6f

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
    // go to chapter 2 page 7
    chapterView.positionViewAtIndex(2, ListView.Beginning)
    var loader = chapterView.currentItem.loader
    loader.loaded.connect(function(l, p) {
        return function() {
           l.item.positionViewAtIndex(p, ListView.Beginning)}
    }(loader, 7))
```

This way when the loader has loaded the item, the function to access the item will be invoked.

Also expose the loader so it can be accessed:

```
Rectangle {
    //...
    property Loader loader : l
    Loader { 
        id: l
        // ...
    }
}
```